# Issue while setting the parameter

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-webflow

I need to set the flow execution parameter to my flow, I tried as follows,

```
studentFlowURL.setParameter("execution","${flowExecutionKey}");
```

It is showing the following exception,

```
 Badly formatted flow execution key '${flowExecutionKey}', the expected format is 'e<executionId>s<snapshotId>'
```

Any suggestion how to pass the value of ${flowExecutionKey} as a string to the execution attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are doing, but try using:

```
${flowExecutionContext.key}
```